# How to use build-in animations UWP

Tags: c#, animation, win-universal-app, windows-10

I have a build-in animation

```
protected virtual void SetUpPageAnimation()
{
    TransitionCollection collection = new TransitionCollection();
    NavigationThemeTransition theme = new NavigationThemeTransition();

    var info = new ContinuumNavigationTransitionInfo();

    theme.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo = info;
    collection.Add(theme);
    this.Transitions = collection;
}
```

I calling this method at MainPage's constructor, but I get those error:

> 'MainPage.SetUpPageAnimation()' is a new virtual member in sealed class 'MainPage'

What is wrong here?
UPDATE -> I added animation in XAML like this and it is works:

```
    <Page.Transitions>
    <TransitionCollection>
        <NavigationThemeTransition>
            <NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
                <SlideNavigationTransitionInfo/>
            </NavigationThemeTransition.DefaultNavigationTransitionInfo>
        </NavigationThemeTransition>
    </TransitionCollection>
</Page.Transitions>
```

Answer (score 0):

A sealed class cannot be used as a base class. Therefore, it is useless to have a virtual method in sealed class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have virtual method(s) in a sealed class.

**[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exaxze9s(v=vs.71).aspx)** says:

> A sealed class cannot be used as a base class, and a virtual method has to be implemented in a derived class, which is a contradiction.